# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing laravel-9 and vuejs3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api, laravel-9

I have a vue3-frontend and a laravel9-backend. I want to send data to the backend using the fetch-api in vue and get the response but unfortunately I get this error message when I click the submit button. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the problem ?

I tried the fruitcake/laravel-cors library but it still did not work

[error from firefox de tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCcqL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCcqL.png)

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

vuejs-code

```
methods: {
    registerUser() {
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/tippspiel/register", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.email,
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
          passwordConfirmation: this.passwordConfirmation,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  }
```

controlelr code laravel

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            "email" => "required|email",
            "username" => "required|min:6|max:15",
            "password" => "required|min:12|max:40",
            "passwordConfirmation" => "required|same:password",
            "ageCheck" => "required|accepted",
            "privacyCheck" => "required|accepted"
        ]);
        return [
            "status" => "ok",
            "id" => 1,
            "username" => $request->username
        ];
    }
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Create new **middleware** called **Cors**, inside of it, put this code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin',
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return \Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
```

Go to **App\Http\Kernel.php**, in the `protected $middleware` array, add this:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

and inside `protected $routeMiddleware` array, add this:

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

In your Route file, add this:

```
Route::middleware(['cors'])->group(function(){
    //your route here
});
```

Run this command inside your laravel folder:

`php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.
Your solution did not work i get a 505-Error

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Internal Server Error - Access-Control-Allow-Origin  is missing